# Python TCP server throws OSError: [WinError 10057] when calling socket.shutdown(1)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have quite a complex TCP/IP server that connects to several clients. I was running into an issue where my clients were not being updated that the socket was closing. I believe I need to call both socket.shutdown() and socket.close() to be able send a server closing advisory to all of the clients. However, I get an OS error whenever I call socket.shutdown().

```
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Or some other way of closing the socket while still sending the advisory to all connected clients? I could always write a custom command that resets all of the clients before calling socket.close(), but something seems wrong with my server. Below is minimum reproducible example.

```
import socket
import selectors

class server_test:

    host = ''
    port = 12345

    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_server()
        self.stop_server()

    #Server Functions    
    def start_server(self):        
        self.lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.lsock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.lsock.listen()
        print("Server starting, listening on ",. (self.host, self.port))
        self.lsock.setblocking(False)
        self.sel.register(self.lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)


    def stop_server(self):
        print("Shutting server down")
        self.lsock.shutdown(1)
        self.lsock.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

> I believe I need to call both socket.shutdown() and socket.close() to be able send a server closing advisory to all of the clients.

No. A `shutdown(1)` on a **connected** socket will send a FIN to the peer to signal that the local system will not send more data, but it might actually accept more data. A `shutdown(0)` will stop receiving data locally and reject any data send by the peer. A `close()` essentially combines a `shutdown(1)` and a `shutdown(0)`.

> ```
>     self.lsock.listen()
>     ...
>     self.lsock.shutdown(1)
> ```

You are trying to tell the peer of `self.lsock` that you will no longer send data. But `self.lsock` is the local listener socket which is not itself connected and thus has no peer. Since you are thus try to do an operation which requires a connected socket on a socket which is not connected (only listening) it will result in the error *"... socket is not connected ..."*.

If you want to shutdown the connection to all clients you actually have to call `shutdown` or `close` on all connected sockets (i.e. result from `self.lsock.accept()` and not on the listener socket.